# Does decommissioning nodes on hadoop cluster hamper performance?

Tags: performance, hadoop

I have 120 node Hadoop cluster, I have removed around 14 nodes in 7 days (each day - 2 nodes were decommissioned) Now users are facing some performance issues, does this decommission really matters. There are 'No' Under-Replicated blocks or Missing blocks. Infact there are heavy job writes as earlier.

Space used: 2.5 PB (Current)
Todal Space : 5.5 PB (current)
CPU Usage: Not crossed 70% (in last 7 Days) Seems to normal as earlier.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programming questions. If you would like to ask about servers in production, then please ask on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: oops i have logged in both accounts.. posted here in hurry..